# Lock access to PDF files by direct link

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Hi want place 1 PDF file for each user in my website. That file have user ID.pdf and is generate by phc. It's about 1500 PDF and they are open in each user by is ID. Problem is that if other user change link to other name can see other PDF files he just need took the right ID number.

How do you limit access?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should help:

I have defined the `$current_user` as `123`. Obviously change this code so you accurately set the value of this variable based on however you're currently handling authentication.

Next step is to move all PDF files into a non-web-accessible directory. This means that it won't be possible to access the PDF by simply typing the URL into the address bar.

Once this is done then define the path, `$pdf_path` to the directory that contains the PDF files.

You can then go to `script.php?user=123`. If the value of `user` matches `$current_user` then the PHP code will fetch the appropriate PDF file and then output it to the user. If you try and specify a different value of `user` to the one you're logged in as then you'll see the error message. Good luck ..

```
<?php

$current_user = 123;
$pdf_path = '/home/pdfs/' . $current_user . '.pdf';

if($current_user == $_GET['user']) {

    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$current_user.".pdf");
    readfile($pdf_path);
    exit;

} else {

    echo "You do not have permission to access this file";

}
```

Comment: Careful that `$current_user` can't be set as something like `../../etc/passwd` or something dangerous.

Comment: But if I have about 3000 users it's time consuming add each file to each user.

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that you're identifying resources in such a way that you can enumerate them by changing the URL. Even large companies have fallen to these "hacks" so it's good you're aware of the issue and want to avoid it.

There's two methods for dealing with this.

1. Ensure that each resource has a *random identifier*, that is it's not linked to the user ID in any way. A UUID, random string of 12 letters or more, or random number of 20 digits should be sufficient for this. These need to be generated in advance and stored in a database or you'll lose track of who owns what file.
2. Use a deterministic hash to generate an identifier, like SHA2-256, based on user ID plus some other secret factor, like a secret key, so they can't be guessed. `6B86B273FF3...B7875B4B` might seem random but it's just the SHA2-256 hash of "1" and attackers will know this. The advantage of a deterministic hash is you can compute this at will, you don't need to save it anywhere. You probably don't need the whole hash, 50-70% of the length is surely unique enough, as collisions with this are designed to be mathematically near impossible.

In either case you'll need to name the files according to your scheme, not by user ID.

Comment: But there is too many generated pdfs to insert 1 by 1 atm they find by id without sql database. I have other pdfs that are inserted 1 by 1 and I did random names with ID at the end and are running great. But insert soo many pdfs 1 by 1 takes too long because now are 1500 but some times are 3000 each month.

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to rename 1500-3000 files. That would probably take <1 second with a simple script.

Comment: I go try do that ty for the hint. Let's see if I can print the final name and ID into a table after creat each file name.

Comment: Success I did it in dos and I print to a txt file hold name without extension = Id and then I print new random name with / in middle of both so I can split them after and send to sql table. Ty for the help